# Extend JavaScript Class from separate file

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, scope

I'm sorry to ask quite a dim question as I'm very new to OOP in JavaScript.

I'm trying to use [John Resig's Simple JavaScript Inheritance method](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/), and ideally I'd like to store this within say `utils.js`, and then use it (using `Class.extend`), throughout the range of script files that my project uses. Is this possible? I've noticed that if I create a subclass from within my `utils.js` file, I can then create a `new` instance of that class from a different script, so that makes me think it might be possible. Does it have something to do with the method being wrapped in an immediately-invoked function expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible, just load the util.js file before the rest. ALthough if I were you (seems like you're starting to have several different files in your project) I'd check out http://requirejs.org/ or some other AMD library to break up your project in modules.

Comment: Thanks, for this - RequireJs is interesting as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible only thing is you have to include Utils.js file before calling Class.extend, so that browser should be able to find the base class.

Browser works like an interpreter, it loads scripts once it finds the script tag

Comment: Thanks, yes was being stupid. Thought that it **was** being loaded in before, but actually looking at the HTML noticed that it wasn't (that's what happens when you have a component based project!)

Answer (score 0):

> Does it have something to do with the method being wrapped in an immediately-invoked function expression?

Yes, in the moment in which the utils.js script is loaded, the method executes and returns the object `Class` to the global scope. From then on, the object can be used in all other files.