# Inheritance of web component in js files

Tags: javascript, inheritance, web-component, custom-element

First component : x-input. A very simple input component who do nothins :

```
(function() {
    class XInput extends HTMLElement {
        static get template() {
            const template = document.createElement('template');
            template.innerHTML = `
                <style>
                    :host {
                        display: block;
                    }
                </style>

                <input id="input">
            `;
            return template;
        }

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
            this.shadowRoot.appendChild(XInput.template.content.cloneNode(true));
        }
    }

    window.customElements.define('x-input', XInput);
})();
```

My component is in a .js file so I don't need to use HTML Import in my client page.
Now, I need a second web component who inherit from x-input :

```
(function() {
    class XInputNumber extends XInput {

    }

    window.customElements.define('x-input-number', XInputNumber);
})();
```

If I try to use this second element in a page -> Uncaught ReferenceError: XInput is not defined.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
        <script src="/bower_components/shadydom/shadydom.min.js"></script>

        <script src="/webcomponents/input/x-input.js"></script>
        <script src="/webcomponents/input/x-input-number.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><x-input></x-input></p>
        <p><x-input-number></x-input-number></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If i write my web components in html files, no problem, but I have to use HTML Imports (I try to do without it).

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: JS classes are visible only in current context scope. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121327/extend-javascript-class-from-separate-file) will be helpful. Also look at `export`.

Comment: Indeed, my objects are into an IIFE. If I remove this IIFE, my example works. But it only works because I declare my two web components in the header. If I want to just use the second web component in my page (so I declare only this one), it will not work (the dependent XInput is not declared anywhere...

Comment: I'm not sure you noticed my mention of `export`. It's not clear what's your platform requirement. You can probably test your code with [`export default class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export). It should be supported in some latest versions of browsers.

Comment: My platform requirement is IE11+, so I cannot use anything...

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, the XInput class is define only in the closure. If you want to reuse it somewhere else you can define it globally, or retreive it with the help of `customElements.get()` method.

In *x-input-number.js* file:

```
(function() {
    var XInput = customeElements.get('x-input');

    class XInputNumber extends XInput {

    }

    window.customElements.define('x-input-number', XInputNumber);
})();
```

or directly:

```
class XInputNumber extends customeElements.get('x-input') {}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. But I have to decalre the x-input.js file into my page. Is it possible to avoid this ?

Comment: I don't understand. How could you use x-input without declaring it before?

Comment: If, in a page, I only use x-input-number, I don't want to declare x-input. I want to just declare x-input-number. If not.the developer who is using these web component must know the inheritance scheme of all web components.

Comment: then you should import the JS file from x-input-number if not yet declared. Use ES6 import/export (not yet natively implemented in all browsers) or add a <script> element dyanmically.

Comment: I will try to add a <script> element dynamically. ES6 import/export is not a solution for me.

Comment: you can use html imports to have the elements link the required scripts themselves

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
  constructor() {
    super("child template");
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
  }
}

customElements.define('x-child', ChildComponent);
```

Parent component:

```
export default class ParentComponent {
  constructor(childTemplate) {
    this.appendChild('foo<div class="refChildContent"></div>bar');
    this.childTemplate = childTemplate;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.querySelector('.refChildContent').innerHTML = this.childTemplate;
  }
}

customElements.define('x-parent', ParentComponent);
```

Result:

```
<x-child>
 foo
 <div class="refChildContent">
    child html
 </div>
 bar
</x-child>
```